# How to write the requirements.txt file with "--no-binary"?

Tags: python, pip

I have to install the python package in the following way,

```sh
pip install --no-binary=protobuf protobuf
```

But How to write `requirements.txt` with `--no-binary=protobuf`?

Comment: Does `pip freeze` not do the right thing? In general, you don't write the requirements.txt by hand.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `pip freeze` only have the following infomation `protobuf==3.6.1`

Comment: You can add options to `requirements.txt` if that's what you mean. The line `--no-binary=protobuf` is a valid requirements line, same as e.g. a line `protobuf --no-binary=protobuf`.

Comment: @hoefling thank you, it works. I also find the answer here <https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#per-requirement-overrides>

Comment: @hoefling you should add this as an answer and it should be accepted :) tnx!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

`pip` supports reading options from requirement files. This means that a requirements file

```
protobuf
--no-binary=protobuf
```

is a valid requirements line, same as e.g. a file consisting out of a single line

```
protobuf --no-binary=protobuf
```

This means that you can also reference other requirement files, e.g.

```
# requirements.txt
-r test_requirements.txt
spam eggs
```

Note, however, that `pip install -r requirements.txt` is roughly equivalent to running `cat requirements.txt | xargs pip`, so the options are applied to the whole command and not a single line or file. For example, this file defines conflicting options:

```
# requirements.txt
spam --no-binary=eggs
bacon --only-binary=eggs
```

An attempt of installing from this requirements file will lead to an error.

Comment: The last section is a useful warning, but do you mean it is not possible to have multiple --no-binary options in one requirements.txt file? i.e. are you saying that the first `--no-binary` option will be automatically applied to every other line no matter what?

Comment: I think what is meant here is that you end up with the equivalent of `pip install spam bacon --no-binary=eggs --only-binary=eggs`, so you could just as well end up having `pip install spam bacon --no-binary=eggs --no-binary=cholesterol`. This would mean each install is privy to all args, but I don't see that as an issue since you likely don't wan't the binary of the same package installed in one case and not another.

Comment: I had an issue with running such setup in github actions, but found out it was `setup.py` that parsed `requirements.txt` and crashed, because some lines were not valid package names. Had to add a filter to skip lines that contained `--no...` in the beginning.